# Difference between LIVE MODE vs TEST MODE in authorized.net

Tags: sandbox

I am integrating the payment gateway to a client's website. But I am having some confusion on the sandbox account. Actually on the sandbox account there is Test Mode and Live Mode. On both modes test cards are accepted.

But in LIVE mode of the sandbox account is the live card accepted and charged?

Answer (score 0):

Test mode is a replication in a sandbox environment. This allows you to test all aspects of your integration before you go live.

Once you've completed your integration, done your testing, and are ready to go live with your application ofcourse you will be charged according to their policy.